# C++ explicit specialization of member template belonging to template class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

In the current C++ standard draft, there is this example in [this paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-15) belonging to the section related to explicit specialization of templates:

```
template<class T> struct A {
   void f(T);
   template<class X1> void g1(T, X1);
   template<class X2> void g2(T, X2);
   void h(T) { }
};

// specialization
template<> void A<int>::f(int);

// out of class member template definition
template<class T> template<class X1> void A<T>::g1(T, X1) { }


// member template specialization
template<> template<class X1> void A<int>::g1(int, X1);  //(1)

// member template specialization
template<> template<>
void A<int>::g1(int, char);                              //(2)
```

In (1) it seems more like `g1` was specialized to be still a function template in the specialized version of A (A< int >), while in (2) it seems like `g1` is itself specialized for its own set template parameters ( (int, from A< int >),  char).

I find there to be a difference between these specializations (again, (1) feels like declaring a new version of `g1` to be used for a "special version" of its "container" `A`, while (2) feels like a specialization regarding `g1` itself (or regarding its own template parameters).

Furthermore, consider this example:

```
template<class T> struct A{
   int f() { return 1; }
}

template<>
int A<int>::f() { return 2; }                            //(3)
```

To me (1) and (3) are the same "kind of specialization", one that is linked to a special version of the "container", while (2) is a specialization of the entity (template) itself.

Does the standard mention this difference or are these two kinds of specialization referred to as the same?

Thank you.

Comment: They are not the same.

Comment: Could you tell me how and where does the standard differentiate between the two?

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer.  `(1)` is a partial specialization, as it still depends on a templated type.  `(3)` is a specialization.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have chosen the example from the standard. If `g1` was declares as: template<class U> void g1(U);, I believe all of them would be explicit specializations.

Answer (score 1):

First, your #3 is equivalent to the first specialization in the cited example, except that the standard’s `f` uses the class’s template parameter in its signature—presumably to illustrate that, since the signature must match for a specialization, template arguments for the class may need to be repeated in the specialization declaration.

Then, the difference is that #1 is a specialization of a *member* of `A<T>` when `T` is `int`—a sort of shorthand for writing a specialization of `A<int>` itself that is mostly the same as the primary template.  In particular, to avoid being misleading, the signature for the member being specialized must be unchanged from the (instantiation of the) primary template.  In this case, that means it’s *still* a template.

On the other hand, #2 is a specialization of a template that *happens* to be a member of `A<int>`—the specialization is of `A<int>::g1` itself, not of “`A<T>::g1` when `T` is `int`” as for #1.  This of course applies only when the member is a template, unlike #3.  (In this case, #2 is a specialization of the very template declared by #1!)

Part of the point of [temp.expl.spec]/15 is that these two cases are *not* strongly distinguished syntactically.  The difference is largely academic: both are surgical changes to a [templated entity](https://books.google.com/books?id=i7M1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT328&lpg=PT328&dq=temploid+entity&source=bl&ots=4hVH6UdLu7&sig=5fwRBq77SEusd8s6OfDdGV61JHE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWtdvNwr3aAhVH6IMKHcK3BDkQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=temploid%20entity&f=false) for certain arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that they mean different things, that is why I thought this difference would be explicitly mentioned in the standard somewhere. I have a question. You said "In particular, to avoid being misleading, the signature for the member being specialized must be unchanged from the (instantiation of the) primary template.". I understand this as: "when you explicitly specialize a member of a class template, its signature must remain the same as the one in the primary template". Is this right? [continued]

Comment: If so, then why does [temp.expl.spec p.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#5) use the following wording: "[...] However, template<> is used in defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class template that is specialized as a class template."? If its signature cannot change, then the only other possibility that I can think of is if the template was specialized also for its own template parameters, i.e. as in #2. Is this correct?

Comment: @user42768: As for mentioning the difference, the pseudo-official terms that I intuit from /15 are “explicit specialization of a member” (that might happen to be a template) and “explicit specialization (of a template)” (that might happen to be a member).

Comment: @user42768: About fixed signatures: yes, that’s what I meant, but there is [implementation divergence](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T9fobkF14Mb54tsI) as to what constitutes a signature: GCC accepts that code, but rejects if the specialization has it not a template at all.

Comment: @user42768: As for /5, I think it’s distinguishing from [defining a member](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Aj6abalDq9thV4dQ) of a specialization _instead_ for some set of template arguments for the member template (and inside a particular specialization of the containing template, as is required).

Comment: Again, thank you for answering. Regarding your last comment, when you say "defining a member of a specialization" you refer to #a (I guess it should be "defining a member of a member of a specialization", no?) and when you say: "for some set of template arguments for the member template" you refer to #b in [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kSkL6lzyg5Oqxati)?

Comment: @user42768: No, my whole last comment is about #b, and that /5 is distinguishing #a _from_ it.

Comment: Ok. So when you use " instead" in that comment, you mean that instead of doing #a, which is not explicitly mentioned in the comment, you can specialize a member of a member template for some template arguments for the member template? Or you use it to say that the specialization will be used instead of the primary template for that set of template arguments? I believe the first answer is what you intended. Natural language seems too ambiguous for specific things like these. Thank you.